# Calling a hiring manager about a hiring decision that is already made

Tags: job-offer

I had a final panel interview last Thursday. The company told me that they'd be calling me on the next day (Friday) with their hiring decision. When Friday came around I had to fly home from the interview, so I never got a phone call. However, on Sunday I received a voicemail from them that was from Friday (My phone carrier didn't send me the voicemail until then). The voicemail said that I should call them back as soon as possible.

I texted the hiring manager about when was the best time to call him back and he said Monday. I called on Monday and he told me he wasn't at the office (because of the holiday I'm assuming) and that he'd call me back that afternoon. It's Tuesday (the next day) and still haven't gotten a call back. Should I wait or send another text message about calling?

Comment: Do you have any other contact information for others? Might want it to be generally known that you are not ignoring their communications.

Comment: No, this person is my only point of contact for this part of the recruitment process. This person knows that I received his voicemail late due to delays from my phone carrier (because he had called me on my flight when my phone wasn't on).

Comment: Nothing bad is going to come from you calling.  So just make the call and stop worring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend trying to call the hiring manager again. If the hiring manager doesn't pick up, leave a message with a good time to call you back and your call back number.

Usually if the recruiter or hiring manager is going to reject you, they won't be as available to talk to you, because they'll be focusing on other candidates. But given Monday was Veteran's Day in USA, your hiring manager may have forgotten that it was a holiday and accidentally told you to call on Monday. I still recommend continuing to follow up, but definitely continue your job search!

Comment: I sent him a text message on Tuesday asking for his availability for a phone call (his preferred method of communication from what I've seen) with no response. I also called him yesterday during business hours and he didn't pick up either. Should I throw in the towel or still be more persistent? I'd think I got rejected at this point but I have a feeling that the manager would have just left me a voicemail saying that I got rejected instead of asking me to call him back as soon as possible.

Comment: @Tetn1s Not everyone leaves a voice mail about rejections unfortunately. You may get a canned rejection email later down the line. But if you got the offer, believe me they'll be chase you down and not the other way around. Better luck on the next one. I remember getting a brutal rejection before I got my best offer last time I went job hunting. You never know when opportunity will come knocking!